# Why are curl request to Nest cloud taking up to 40 seconds?

Tags: curl, nest-api

I have a c client which is using libcurl to send curl request to Nest backend and I need to specify a timeout. What is an ideal value?

I currently have 30 seconds which worked for a while but about 2 weeks ago my code broke down. I tested with 60 seconds and it worked again.

Since I can't abort the curl request. My cleanup takes order of minutes. Is there a better solution I can consider?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing. The longest response I've ever seen is 1000ms which was over a week ago during an incident. I've been hitting the API all day and requests are averaging 260ms.

Can you post your curl request?